# Restar un numero con fecha y hora en mysql

Tags: php, mysql

en la realización de un proyecto necesito que mis valores sean reducidos al paso del tiempo , y también tenga alteraciones en mi base de datos , sea php con mysql . 
para que se pueda comprender lo que quiero que salga tengo mis variables:

```
 idvar   var  fecha y hora de ingreso
 1        30   11/27/19   06:30
 2        40   11/27/19   06:35
 3        50   11/27/19   06:37
```

y lo que deseo es pasado un determinado tiempo(1 minuto) reduzca -1 , digamos la variable 1 que es 30 sea 29

```
idvar var  fecha y hora de ingreso hora actual
1      29   11/27/19   06:30          06:31

idvar var  fecha y hora de ingreso hora actual
1      28   11/27/19   06:30          06:32
```

.....

y asi con las demas hasta que lleguen a 0 , en este caso como es 30 significa que pasado 30 minutos se convertiría en 0 tambien deseo alterar los numeros en otras horas digamos desde las 12:00 - 12:30 , que el variable 1 que es 30 aumente su numero + 20

```
 idvar var  fecha y hora de ingreso hora actual
 1     50  11/27/19   06:30          12:11
```

y terminado 12:30 vuelva a su numero anterior sea reducido o no

```
 idvar var  fecha y hora de ingreso hora actual
 1     30  11/27/19   06:30          12:31
```

quisiera saber si hay alguna forma en php para poder actualizar estas variables a mi base de datos , y sea actualizado automaticamente espero se pueda comprender , gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quizás te interesaría investigar el tema de los jobs de base de datos, en este caso, event que es como se llaman en MySql si no me equivoco.

Este es un ejemplo para insertar, pero se podría hacer para más cosas...
CREATE event evento_prueba ON schedule every 1 minute do INSERT INTO prueba VALUES(now());

Aquí tienes unos enlaces: [http://juancarlosmolinos.net](http://juancarlosmolinos.net/bases-de-datos/mysql/ddl-y-dml/jobs-en-mysql/) [https://codigofacilito.com/](https://codigofacilito.com/articulos/eventos-mysql)

En el segundo tienes algunos ejemplos de varias líneas. Espero te sirva de ayuda compañero.

Un saludo!

Comment: Si, efectivamente, la documentación oficial es la que mencionas compañero, tiene un "+" al final del enlace, por si quieres modificarlo :)

Comment: Muchas gracias ,la verdad no me acordaba de los eventos me ayudo muchisimo en mysql se puede crear los eventos de manera muy facil y solo ingresar si deseo hacer un insert en mi caso un update porque restare un valor ,me sirvio mucho :)